# Can this Duplicate message be removed?

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates

[This answer on escape velocity](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21718/23186) is better and simpler for laymen than [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4691/23186), and should not be closed as duplicate.

As soon as read the first paragraph from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21718/23186), I got it! As opposed to the mathematically intense answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/4691/23186) which I could not follow.

**Feature request:** 
Perhaps *[Simple answer]*, or a rating scale to questions can be implemented whereby readers can vote if an answer is for laymen or geared for more knowledgeable people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that can be done is a merge. I did just perform that, so both answers now are a part of the second question.